# failing to open connection between R and SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

[image: msss]
[image: odbc]
[image: create new data source]
[image: server setup]
[image: test]
[image: TestServer]
[image: error]
[image: driver check]

I have edited this post by adding all of the above screen shots in case anyone can spot if/where i'm going wrong. I followed the example for getting this working here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwzIx7CEn0Y . I seem to be following exactly what they do in the video yet it still doesn't work!

original post:

I have just installed ms sql server management studio on my home computer. I'm trying to import a data table into the sql server via R studio.

I have run this code:

```
library(RODBC)

connection <- odbcDriverConnect(
  "driver = {SQL Server};
   server = DESKTOP-4M7G7RU\\SQLEXPRESS;
   database = master;
   trusted_connection = true;
   uid = DESKTOP-4M7G7RU/mogwa"
)
```

and receive this warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("driver = {SQL Server};\n   server = DESKTOP-4M7G7RU\\SQLEXPRESS;\n   database = master;\n   trusted_connection = true;\n   uid = DESKTOP-4M7G7RU/mogwa") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("driver = {SQL Server};\n   server = DESKTOP-4M7G7RU\\SQLEXPRESS;\n   database = master;\n   trusted_connection = true;\n   uid = DESKTOP-4M7G7RU/mogwa") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Now keep in mind i'm a total noob and have never install sql server before so maybe there's something i was supposed to do in the set up process, or maybe i have written something incorrectly in the R code.

My first thought was i don't have the required driver installed. I tried searching for 'odbc' in my computer and found something called 'ODBC Data Source Administrator (32-bit)'. I clicked on the 'Drivers' tab for this and it shows 'SQL Server' within an 'ODBC Drivers that are installed on your system' list so presumably the driver is there.

Not sure how to proceed from here?

I tried the R code with and without the 'uid = DESKTOP-4M7G7RU/mogwa' and i don't have a password for connecting to SQL Server so didn't see a need to have that in the R code.

Comment: Try it with the string all on one line (trusted connection means uid is not required) - There are two versions of the odbc control panel, one for 32 bit & one for 64 bit - the bitness must match everywhere - Note that management studio will not install SQL Express so make sure you have it installed.

Comment: okay have tried with string on same line and doesn't work. I can see 32 bet and 64 bit drivers. I followed this guide for setting them up with a dns: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/965049/how-to-set-up-a-microsoft-sql-server-odbc-data-source

Comment: I tried this with dns names i created and didn't work. Apparently the data source name is not found. theodbcDriverConnect("mydnsname", uid = "myuserid")

Comment: I just don't understand why it's saying no default driver supplied when i run the original code i posted. "driver = {SQL Server}" seems to be what i'm supposed to use for that argument and i can see the driver on my computer. What else can i do here! lol

Comment: Please check all drivers and dsns with `print(odbcDataSources())`. Do you see SQL Server and/or *TestServer*?

Comment: I've added a new screen shot showing the results from running the print(odbcDataSources()). It's showing TestServer and mogwai for "SQL Server". I set up the mogwai dns under the 'System DSN' and Testserver under the 'User DSN'. Not sure what the difference is regarding connecting to the driver.

Comment: I have finally figured out why it wasn't working. I was using the value 'true' instead of 'yes' for the Trusted_Connection. I'm new to using sql and now understand it doesn't have boolean true/false values like most languages. I'm not entirely sure if i saw an example with true in it or if i converted it in my mind to true as i'm so used to coding true in these situations. I only realised my error when i stumbled upon this site: https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/